# SQLite database not displaying all the records

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have created a SQLite database. It is not showing all the records: it gives one record only.
I have inserted more than one record, but the database is sowing only one record.

The show record method is displaying only the last inserted record.
I want to display all the records saved in the database.

The records are successfully added.

```
import android.content.Context;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.widget.TextView;




public class ViewPeople extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textViewName;

    private static final String SELECT_SQL = "SELECT * FROM persons";

    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    private Cursor c;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_people);
        openDatabase();

        textViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);




        c = db.rawQuery(SELECT_SQL, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        showRecords();
    }

    protected void openDatabase() {
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("PersonDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    }

    protected void showRecords() {

        String name = c.getString(1);
        textViewName.setText(name);



    }
```

Comment: You are not looping through your recordset

Comment: You have only one TextView. Even if you loop through all the records, have some mechanism so show them. You can display them all in a single text view using a separator. Or have a RecyclerView

Answer (score 2):

Your need to fetch data in a loop.

```
if (c.moveToFirst()){
   do{
       String name = c.getString(1);
      // do what ever you want here
   }while(c.moveToNext());
}
c.close();
```

Comment: not working I have put this code on all possible places

Comment: c = db.rawQuery(SELECT_SQL, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        showRecords();

Comment: @GauravAwasthi `c.moveToFirst()` must be put only in the `showRecords()` method.

Comment: By the way, I'd change this `if (c.moveToFirst()){` to `if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()){`

Answer (score 0):

Use this lib to view database at runtime.

`com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:0.4.0`

and to view all records you must use this code.

`if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                   tvName.setText(cursor.getString(0)); 
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());`

Answer (score -1):

It's not the mistake, but by default the Sqlite return only one record. if want all the records then you need to do it using the loop.

try to do following, remove **c.moveToFirst();
        showRecords();** and add the following code.

```
while(c.moveToNext()){
   showRecords();
}
```

and in showRecords method remove **textViewName.setText(name);** and add textViewName.append(name+"\n");

Comment: `by default the Sqlite return only one record` ... **WHAT?! WHEN?! HOW?!** - You must be joking.

Comment: when you try to fetch the record i mean when you use get method withou loop.

Comment: The cursor returns **ALL the rows** you selected in the query. It's then up to you to correcly fetch them one by one.

Comment: Not Working it still giving the one record

Comment: c = db.rawQuery(SELECT_SQL, null);
      
        showRecords();
    }

    protected void openDatabase() {
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("PersonDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    }

    protected void showRecords() {

        if (c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                String name = c.getString(1);
                // do what ever you want here
            }while(c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();

        }


    } gives blank record nothing is showing

Comment: it gives only one record

Comment: while(c.moveToNext()){

Comment: name+=c.getString(1);
}

and then set this name to your textview.

Comment: @GauravAwasthi If you don't move between records, you'll never see them. But they are there.